# Cisco router https warning

Tags: router, https

My web browser displays a warning when I try and login to a cisco router. The https certificate is untrusted and I am asked whether to proceed anyway.

How do I make this warning go away? It happens with any web browser so ideally I'd like to fix the certificate on the router rather than accept an invalid certificate each time.

The router is Cisco SA520

Comment: If you use Firefox, you can add the invalid certificate to your exceptions list and it will no longer prompt you to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to accept it once, not every time.

I think installing proper certificate is overkill for this. Self signed certificate still works well for local network environment and a warning will appear anyway if someone will try to do man in the middle attack.

So ideally, you just accept this exception once and after that it should not bother you much.

**EDIT** on your comment:

`Can't I generate one that is trusted and upload it to the router?`

This is called [self-signed certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate). (Unless you are a [Certificate Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) - joke). That what it is currently router uses. If your device allows to install external certificates than you can use offer of some companies which do generate free SSL certificates, but there is no guarantee that this free SSL certificate will be accepted by browser. So you can end up with same problem even with free generated SSL certificate.

I do not want to promote any company here to prevent consequences, but Google search "free SSL certificate" will help you to find one.

Properly generated paid SSL certificate will remove security message. Please, notice that certificate will last limited amount of time after which you will have to generate new one (and pay more). It can be one year or two years, I am not sure.

So that is why I say it is overkill. How often will you access you router? 10 times per day? On my vision and own experience you configure router and after that rarely touch it.

Comment: Chrome asks to confirm the certificate every time. Is it overkill because you would have to purchase an ssl certificate? Can't I generate one that is trusted and upload it to the router?

Comment: See my edit in the post